# How to spawn independent sub-cmds from Windows cmd script?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

How to run a number independent Windows cmd scripts by making a Windows cmd script that launches the other scripts, e.g. having a `do_all.cmd` script with:

```
alfa.cmd
bravo.cmd
charlie.cmd
```

The running of `do_all.cmd` should then cause `alfa.cmd`, `bravo.cmd`, and `charlie.cmd` to start in parallel.

Is this possible ?

Comment: Use [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: You might want to look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257571/call-command-vs-start-with-wait-option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The START command can do that; type `START /?` to see all the details